# tensorflows always shows me these lines

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2020-08-26 00:03:56.687961: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.340406: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.378127: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-08-26 00:03:58.378299: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.382043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.385656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.386883: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.392017: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.394241: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.403788: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.404082: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-26 00:03:58.404778: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-08-26 00:03:58.414602: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x18940170110 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-26 00:03:58.414776: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415042: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415268: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415381: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415477: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415696: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415800: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.415949: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-26 00:03:58.416126: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-26 00:03:59.149169: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-26 00:03:59.149272: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-08-26 00:03:59.149331: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-08-26 00:03:59.149561: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2905 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
```

I have installed everything correct still while running a program of tensorflow in python .......it first shows me this then the output .Its not a warning or error
please someone help me to fix it .........

Comment: This is normal information provided by tensorflow, there is no need to "fix it", because there is no problem at all. If you had GPU troubles then these information log will give you valuable information on how to fix it.

Comment: my reputation is less than 15 ..its not recording it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following two lines at the top of your file.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
```

Use the above code to disable all loggings.
Here are the three levels

```
0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
1 = INFO messages are not logged
2 = INFO, WARNING messages are not logged
3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not logged
```

You can choose which level of logging you want.